# I2C Level Shifter 3.3V Raspi 5V Arduino Mega

Tags: pi-3, i2c, arduino

I am connecting RasPi (Master) via I2C with Arduino Mega (Slave).

Do I need a level shifter for this or is it non compulsory?

As of now my code runs for some time before I get a Remote I/O Error message and the program stops running.

Could this be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

RasPi GPIO is 3.3 V while Arduino is 5 V. It will work for a while but one day the RasPi won't work anymore.

Consider using cheap [TXB0104](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txb0104.pdf) (Sparkfun sell breakout boards) bi-directional level convertors.

They are pretty simple to use and protect your RasPi and Arduino.